# Choosing Minimum Android App SDK

Tags: android, sdk

I know there is other questions about how to choose min SDK but they are seems to old. In the current situation which sdk can be choosen as min sdk? And how important is it, I mean If I choose for example 4.3 version over 5.0 What are the newly enabled features in 5.0 but not available in 4.3,what am I going to lose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This link provides you with all the information you need to know...
you can get all the recent statistics.. https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

and to get Changes with respect to API 21 Refer this link.. It has complete details on what you get extra by using API 21 and what you dont get in older versions... https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html

Comment: It includes number of devices but I need compare two sdk version. I mean I want to know what will I lose if I choose an old version.

Comment: you mean in terms of features??

Comment: Yeah, for example I just learned that setting sdk value to "11" disables the screen compatibility mode. I need to compare for example 18 or 21 API level to see which features will not be enable in a spesific version.

Comment: Check My updated Post for the same You get All the details that are enabled with every new API from official google documentation... The one i have posted is for API 21

Answer (score 5):

When you are creating a new app. You get the option what minimum api you will go for. On that page there is a link "Help me choose"

[image]

You will be greeted by a chart like the picture above. It is up to you. But i would suggest API 16 since it has most support from libraries i have used and you cover most phones

Comment: What is the difference between these versions? Is the number of devices only parameter?

Comment: With newer versions come better support for newer functions.
Thats why we also have support libraries. They are there to help lower api levels handle newer functions better. The biggest difference is the number of devices. But also functionality. Some libraries dont support all the api levels because they are using newer methods that the phones running on those Android versions would not be able to run

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Platform Versions statistics from [developer.android.com dashboards](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) to see the relative number of devices running a given version of the Android platform.